# Split complex system of equations into two real systems

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have a complex system of equations in 3 unknowns, like this one:

$$
\pmatrix{
40 & -20 & 0\\
-20 & 20-20j & 30+10j\\
4 & -5 & 1
}
\pmatrix{
x_1+j x_2\\
y_1+j y_2\\
z_1+j z_2\\
}=
\pmatrix{
10\\
0\\
0\\
}
$$

Here are solutions:

[image: solutions]

I want to split the matrix with complex numbers to two matrices with real numbers. However the imaginary matrix would only have one equation:

$$-20y_2+10z_2=0$$

What am I doing wrong?

Or is it possible to split such a system to two systems in the first place? (two "real" systems?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ should be split into real and imaginary parts.

The system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
40(x_1+jx_2)-20(y_1+jy_2)=10\\
-20(x_1+jx_2)+(20-20j)(y_1+jy_2)+(30+10j)(z_1+jz_2)=0\\
4(x_1+jx_2)-5(y_1+jy_2)+(z_1+jz_2)=0
\end{cases}
$$
so you get
$$
\begin{cases}
40x_1-20y_1=10\\
40x_1-20y_2=0\\
-20x_1+20y_1+20y_2+30z_1-10z_2=0\\
-20x_2-20y_1+20y_2+10z_1+30z_2=0\\
4x_1-5y_1+z_1=0\\
4x_2-5y_2+z_2=0
\end{cases}
$$
which are six equations in six unknowns.

However, there's no need to do this, because complex numbers are as well behaved as the real numbers, when solving linear systems.

Comment: yea assume that each unknown is alpha + j beta .. I know that there's no need, it's just that my calculator can handle real systems only

Comment: @MinaMichael Yes, that's the idea: $X=x_1+ix_2$, $Y=y_1+iy_2$ and $Z=z_1+iz_2$.

Comment: okay but I can't solve the complex part. It only gives one equation. What do I do about that??

Comment: @MinaMichael Just do properly complex multiplication.

Comment: Oh I see! You caught my mistake .. there are equations that have components from the two systems (the ones in the middle). I wished I could have two separate systems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just separate the real and imaginary parts all the way through.

In terms of arithmetic complex-numbers are isomorphic with 2-D vectors.  However, this would give you twice as much work to do.

The hardness of the equation(s) is because they involve a 3 by 3 matrix, and 3 unknown quantities, and this does not simplify by separating real and imaginary components (parts).

Comment: but I tried and the complex part gave me one equation $$-20Y+10Z=0$$ What am I doing wrong??

Comment: ...the idea about the splitting is that my calculator can solve 3x3 real equations so I want to split them to two and give them to it